# Prevent launchd.peruser to launch daemons

Tags: macos, launchd

### Configuration :

Mac OSX 10.7.5 on a Mac Mini mid 2010.

### Context

I installed [MobileGo](http://www.wondershare.com/android-manager/) a while ago, a backup solution for Android, and I am using [Spotify](https://www.spotify.com/) for music streaming. *Important* : I am also using [Soundsticks](http://store.apple.com/us/product/H2268VC/B/harman-kardon-soundsticks-iii-21-channel-sound-system) speakers to output my music by USB.

---

### Problem

This morning, I noticed that my speakers were acting weird, the music played for ± 2 minutes, and then stopped : no more sound on the speakers. I had to unplug / replug to get it work again (for 2 extra minutes).

I checked the console, and I have noticed these error triggered every 1m40s :

> 18/03/13 09:27:06,762 com.apple.launchd.peruser.505:
>   (**com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon**[3455])
>   posix_spawn("/Users/mjugan12/Library/Application
>   Support/wondershare_mobilego/**MobileGoDaemon**.app", ...): Permission
>   denied
>
> 18/03/13 09:27:06,763 com.apple.launchd.peruser.505:
>   (**com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon[**3455]) Exited with code: 1 18/03/13
>
> 09:27:06,764 com.apple.launchd.peruser.505:
>   (**com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon**) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10
>   seconds

Result: exact same timing than my speakers' breaks.

*Note : this error happens even if my speakers are unplugged || Spotify is not launched.*

### Attempt

1. I uninstalled MobileGo and MobileGoDaemon with *AppZapper*. Didn't
       fixed, but I now have :

   > 18/03/13 10:18:47,866 com.apple.launchd.peruser.505:
   >   (com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon[8011])
   >   posix_spawn("/Users/mjugan12/Library/Application
   >   Support/wondershare_mobilego/MobileGoDaemon.app", ...): **No such file or directory**

   I though *AppZapper* would have remove all the daemon calls, but no.
2. I've found [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4850586?start=0&tstart=0) and [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4238141?start=0&tstart=0) topics, searched for any pList
   about MobileGoDaemon, didn't find anything else.
3. Last step, I located `com.apple.launchd.peruser.505` (505 is my user
   ID) in `private/var/db/launchdb.db/`, found the `override.plist`,
   and didn't see `com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon` anywhere. I tried to
   add :

   > `<key>com.wondershare.mobilegodaemon</key>`
   >
   > `<dict>`
   >       `<key>Disabled</key>`
   >       `<true/>` 
   >   `</dict>`

   But no luck...

If somebody has any clue about what's going on, please help!

If you want further informations (logs or stuff), I'll post it ASAP.